# android file.getUsableSpace returns zero with getExternalFilesDir(null), only after deleting other files

Tags: android

I have an app that sometimes needs to save files. Before writing, it checks usable space on the device. Here is the code I'm using to check space, with log statements.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
Log.d("Classname", "external storage state is " + state);
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator);
Log.d("Classname", "file exists " + file.exists());
long usableSpace = file.getUsableSpace();
Log.d("Classname", "Space available " + usableSpace);
```

I've received a bug report that after deleting other files, around 3-5 MB, on a device that has around 3 GB free, getUsableSpace is returning 0 when trying to save another file.

The log before adding the first file:

```
11:21:46.879: external storage state is mounted
11:21:46.879: file exists true
11:21:46.880: Space available 3185496064
```

The log after deleting the first file, trying to add a second:

```
11:21:57.811: external storage state is mounted
11:21:57.822: file exists false
11:21:57.823: Space available 0
```

I have external storage permissions in my manifest, and have tried checking whether the storage is mounted and calling mkdir() when creating the external storage file, and the bug persists. I also had the tester reboot the device, thinking it might have just gotten into a weird state.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The solution was in the way deleting happens – if the last file deleted is gone, I was cleaning up the directory getExternalStorageDir was looking for, so when I tried to getUsableSpace on it, the directory didn't exist.